# Any tool/Add-on to separate inline style from .aspx to .css files in VS2012?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

Is there any tool/Add-on to separate inline style from `.aspx` to `.css` files in VS2012?

I need to separate the existing `.aspx` inline styles to a different `.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

As i know - no (may be there is somewhere), but you can try to use firefox plugin Dust-Me to get styles file and then remove (by yourself) all inline styles in aspx.